# How to wait for dbus signal trigger using txdbus?

Tags: python, twisted

e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cocagne/txdbus/master/doc/tutorial_examples/signal_client

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from txdbus import client, error

def onSignal( tickCount ):
    print 'Got tick signal: ', tickCount
    
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main():

    try:
        cli   = yield client.connect(reactor)
        robj  = yield cli.getRemoteObject( 'org.example', '/Signaller' )
        robj.notifyOnSignal( 'tick', onSignal )
    except error.DBusException, e:
        print 'DBus Error:', e
                
reactor.callWhenRunning(main)
reactor.run()
```

In the above code sample, how can we wait for onSignal method being called using twisted?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "wait for" `onSignal` to be called.  Instead, `onSignal` is *how you wait* for the `tick` signal from DBus.

What do you want to happen on each tick?  Put that code in `onSignal`.  What do you want to happen after you wait for `onSignal`?  Put that code in `onSignal`.